# MVC5 decimal? field editfor with decimal seperator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cultureinfo

I have a decimal field in my modal.

```
public partial class MyModel
{
    public decimal? BudgetAantalDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

I show this in my form with

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BudgetAantalDecimal, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control decimal-small inline" } })
```

When I fill in the value 100 the field is filled in the model. When I fill in the value 100.66 the value is null in  my model.

When I change my language setting from Dutch to US format I can use the value 100.66. My customer has the Dutch language setting set in Windows. How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Is your server processing the request in the Dutch culture?

Comment: How can I verify that? If I go to my control panel of the server and on the first tab where it says format. If I change from Dutch to US then it works. The system locale is still US. The first tab is only for logged in user I think. In Dutch the decimal seperator is a dot and in US a comma

Comment: The ASP.NET process should report Thread.CurrentUICulture/CurrentCulture. That's what will be used when parsing numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a custom model binder to deal with the changing punctuation when it comes to decimals. [This blog](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/) goes over step by step, but I'll recreate some here in case the link breaks.

First, you need to create the binder:

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        var modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        var actualValue = null;
        try {
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue, 
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e) {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        return actualValue;
    }
}
```

After that, all you need to do is add it to your config so it knows about it:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());

    // All that other stuff you usually put in here...
}
```

Comment: That modelbinder works. I no longer get a null value. But when I fill in number 100.75 The converted value is 10075. So should I not use CurrentCulture but always US? Because the 75 should be after the decimal seperator

Comment: I would put a breakpoint in that try block, and see what it gives you for `valueResult.AttemptedValue`. You can then use the Immediate Window to try out the different cultures.

Comment: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture this works on my dev and customer site.

Comment: The only thing that I don't get is why if I use dutch setting and no model binder the value gets null instead of for example when I use 100.75 translated into 10075

Comment: It doesn't work because it throws an exception when trying to convert the string to a decimal, so instead of blowing up it just says there is no value.

Comment: Can't the validation with jquery get this and show the user what format he should use?

Comment: You can write a function to force it to either `.` or `,`. However, this is a problem specific to ASP.NET MVC, and other platforms may not have similar problems. jQuery thinks it is a valid value for its purposes.